# Writing a matrix with imaginary eigenvalues in a block-diagonal form

Tags: linear-algebra, characteristic-polynomial

Trying to write a 4x4 matrix $C$ in a block diagonal form $A$ where $C=QAQ^{-1}$ is valid and I am also supposed to find $Q$. I thought I could reach this in a similar fashion to finding Jordan form through using eigenvalues and eigenspaces.

However, the matrix $C$ has the characteristic polynomial ${\lambda}^4-1=0$ which leads to the eigenvalues -1, 1 but also $-i$ and $i$. I am assured that the characteristic polynomial is correct. This is given as a hint in the question.

Unfortunately, I am not getting any feedback from prof or assistants other than that I am not supposed to get on with imaginary numbers (Despite this not being mentioned anywhere in the question). So I am stumped on how to move forward. I am refraining from adding the matrix here since I do not want a solution to the question I'm supposed to solve myself, rather I'd like to know how to proceed further or at least a similar example. At this point, the lack of useful help from my course is driving me crazy. Excuse my frustration. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Not a complete solution, but a hint**

Hint: your block diagonal form will look something like
$$
\pmatrix{
1 & & & \\
& -1 & & \\
& & & 1\\
& & -1 & }
$$
with the second block being the part corresponding to the complex eigenvalues.

It might help to look at the $2 \times 2$ matrix $M = \pmatrix{ 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0}$ and compare what you get from diagonalizing it (the matrix $Q$ has complex entries; after diagonalization, you get a diagonal matrix with  $\pm i$ on the diagonal) and what you get by block-diagonalizing it (you get back $M$!). And then maybe look at
$$
M = \pmatrix{c & -s \\
s & c}
$$
where $c$ and $s$ are the sine and cosine of some angle like $\pi/3$, and see whether you can do something similar. By then, you'll be 90% of the way to being done.

Incidentally, there's a cheap trick that's perfectly valid: you could say that $A = C$ and $Q = I$ represents $C$ as a block diagonal matrix with exactly one $4 \times 4$ block. But it's pretty clear that this isn't what your teacher really wants. (I might suggest considering finding a different teacher, or taking the course a different year, if that's an option...)

Comment: I'm sorry the first example got me confused. Diagonalising M leads to eigenvalues $i$ and $-i$ and eigenvectors $(-i,1)$ and $(i,1)$ respectively. This does not lead to $Q$ having complex entries in the diagonal but rather one compex entry in the diagonal. Did you perhaps mean $A$?

Comment: The diagonalizing matrix generally has the eigenvectors as its columns (or its inverse does, depending which side you put the inverse!). When I said "you get $\pm i$ on the diagonal", I meant "the diagonal of the resulting diagonalized matrix"; I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to calculate the eigenvectors, e.g. $v_1$, $v_2$, $v_3$ and $v_4$. Let the last two be the complex eigenvectors.
2. Calculate $w_1 := \frac{1}{\lVert v_1 \rVert}v_1$, $w_2 := \frac{1}{\lVert v_2 \rVert}v_2$ and $w_3 := \frac{1}{\lVert v_3 \rVert}v_3$.
3. Then $Q := \left(w_1, w_2, \frac{1}{\lVert \mathrm{Re}(w_3)\rVert}\mathrm{Re}(w_3), \frac{1}{\lVert \mathrm{Im}(w_3)\rVert}\mathrm{Im}(w_3) \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$ should do the job.

Comment: What is the reasoning behind this approach? Could you give me a keyword so I can read more about why this approach works?

Comment: Did work in your case? This does not really have a name. But "orthogonal normal/canonical form" should give you results. You search for a normal form that consists of rotation matrices $\begin{pmatrix} \cos(\alpha) & - \sin(\alpha) \\ \sin(\alpha) & \cos(\alpha) \end{pmatrix}$.